# Clean up Redisson pub/sub listeners when assoicated object is 'stale'

Tags: java, websocket, redis, redisson

I'm trying to implement a simple Websocket application in Java that is able to scale horizontally, by using Redis and the Redisson library.

The Websocket server basically keeps track of connected clients, and sends message that are received to an Rtopic - this works great.

To consume, I have code that adds a listener when a client is registered : it associated a Client object with a listener by:

```
private static RedissonClient redisson = RedissonRedisServer.createRedisConnectionWithConfig();
public static final RTopic subcriberTopic = redisson.getTopic("clientsMapTopic");

public static boolean sendToPubSub(ConnectedClient q, String message) {
        boolean[] success = {true};
        MessageListener<Message> listener = new MessageListener<Message>() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(CharSequence channel, Message message) {
                logger.debug("The message is : " + message.getMediaId());

                try {
                    logger.debug("ConnectedClient mediaid: " + q.getMediaid() + ",Message mediaid " + message.getMediaId());
                    if (q.getMediaid().equals(message.getMediaId())) {
                        // we need to verify if the message goes to the right receiver
                        logger.debug("MESSAGE from PUBSUB to (" + q.getId() + ") @ " + q.getSession().getId() + " " + message);
                        // this is the actual message to the websocket client
                        // this executes on the wrong connected client when the connection is closed and reopened
                        q.getSession().getBasicRemote().sendText(message.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    success[0] = false;
                }
            }
        };
        int listenerId = subcriberTopic.addListener(Message.class, listener);
}
```

The problem I am observing is as follows:

- initial connection from client registers listener associated with that object
- sent message to the ws server gets picked up by listener and sent properly
- disconnect websocket - create new connection - new listener gets created
- sent message to the ws server gets picked up by same original listener and uses that connected client instead of the newly registered one
- sending fails (because client and ws connection don't exist)and is not processes further

It seems I just need to remove the listener for the client if the client gets removed, but I haven't found a good way to do that because although I see in the debugger that the listener has the associated connected client object, I'm unable to retrieve them without adding code for that.

Am I observing this correctly and what is a good way to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

When I was writing the question, I kind of leaned to an answer that I had in mind and tried, which worked.
I added a ConcurrentHashmap to keep track of the relation between the connected client and the listener.
In the logic where I handled websocket error that pointed to a client removing, I then removed the listener that was associated (and the entry from the map).
Now it works as expected.

small snippet:

```
int listenerId = subcriberTopic.addListener(Message.class, listener);
clientListeners.put(q,(Integer)listenerId);
```

And then in the websocket onError handler that triggers the cleanup:

```
// remove the associated listener
int listenerIdForClient = MessageContainer.clientListeners.get(cP);
MessageContainer.subcriberTopic.removeListener((Integer) listenerIdForClient);
// remove entry from map
MessageContainer.clientListeners.remove(cP);
```

Now the listener gets cleaned up properly and the next time a new listener gets created and handles the messages.